# ActiveModelSerializer conditional association rendering

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree, active-model-serializers, rails-api

In a spree API application, I want to render associated comments of a `product` only if the user is `admin`. Else simply render `product` detail.

I'm using `0.10.0.rc2` of `active_model_serializers`

```
gem 'active_model_serializers', '~> 0.10.0.rc2'
```

I'm overriding the `product` serializer of spree as follows:

```
Spree::ProductSerializer.class_eval do
  attributes :stock_available

  has_many :comments, serializer: MyApplication::CommentSerializer

  # http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/active_model_serializers#Associations
  def filter(keys) # <--- Option 1
    keys.delete(:comments) unless scope.admin?
    keys
  end

  def include_comments? # <--- Option 2
    scope.admin?
  end
end
```

Here `comments` is a polymorphic table. However none of the two option seems to be working. Any idea whats wrong here?

I went through [RailsCast episode](http://railscasts.com/episodes/409-active-model-serializers) on active-model-serializer. But it doesn't seems to be working here.

Also the strange thing is, when I put `binding.pry` in either of these two methods, the request at `/api/products/:id` doesn't pause at `binding.pry`.

Thanks